# mpmovieplayerviewcontroller not play audio in ios 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

I am upgrade my app to iOS 6 and now in app the mpmovieplayerviewcontroller not play streaming audio

in my app.It show front interface of player but not play audio and in console following warnings are

coming:

```
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay

[MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0

 [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.

[MPAVController] Autoplay: Ending background task assertion (10) for playback stall
```

I find it so hardly everywhere but can't succeeded.how can i solve this?

Comment: Are you trying on simulator? or device. I had several problems in the past with other `AVFoundation` framework on simulator, but not on device.